# Как с помощью окружения theorem создать новое окружение, которое автоматически нумерует определения в тексте?

Tags: latex

Сделал вот так

```
\newenvironment{opredelenie}{
    \newtheorem{theorem}{Определение}
    \begin{theorem}     
    \end{theorem}
}
```

Первый вызов выводится как надо, но проблема в том, что при вызове повторно происходит ошибка

> Command \theorem already defined. \begin{opredelenie}

из-за того что newtheorem вызывается тоже повторно
Можно-ли как то сделать так, чтобы эта команда вызывалась единожды?

Comment: посмотрите на [примеры](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=theorem+environment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Совершенно не понятно, что вызывает у Вас сложности с заданием окружения командой `\newtheorem`. Эта команда сама создает окружение с указанным именем и создает соответствующий счетчик. Для примера, я определил новые окружения для теорем и для определений и вывел значения их счетчиков, чтобы было видно, что для каждого такого окружения создается именно свой уникальный счетчик. Если нужна более тонкая настройка заголовка и текста теоремы (определения), то можно еще воспользоваться пакетом [**nccthm**](http://mirrors.mi.ras.ru/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/ncctools/doc/nccthm.pdf).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Теорема}
\newtheorem{definit}{Определение}

\begin{document}
    \begin{theorem}
       Текст какой-то теоремы
    \end{theorem}

    \begin{definit}
        Текст определения
    \end{definit}

    \noindent
    Счетчик для определений: \thedefinit \\
    Счетчик для теорем: \thetheorem
\end{document}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]